# IBM Mobilefirst 8 ChallengHandler issue on ios device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm currently using IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0. and Datapower as reverse proxy server.

I have implemented Challenge handler as given in 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/datapower-integration/

Everything is working fine for iPhone 7 Plus and iPhone 6 plus but whenever I am running application on other iPhone (iPhone 6 or iPhone 6s) below method never getting called -

```
dataPowerChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse = function(response) {

if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
    return false;
}
var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search('j_security_check');

if (indicatorIdx >= 0) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

};

Is there any difference in Plus and other iPhones?

I am using MFP Platform version - 8.0.0.00-20170131-101344

XCode version 8.0

ios version 10.0

Comment: Are the devices , where you see the issue , running a different version of the OS? And what does the network capture show - the one that shows the request and response at the server end. The clue will lie there

Comment: Observed the Datapower logs. The request from iPhone 7 Plus device going to api/preauth/v1/preauthorize but request from iPhone 6 is going to api/registration/v1/self. Why this difference?

Comment: Initially I m calling below function-      WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName).then(
        function (accessToken) {
            WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onSuccess");
        },
        function (response) {
            WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    });

Comment: Are you running applications on both devices for the first time? Or is it that one device already had it installed , while the other one is recent install

Answer (score 0):

I do not recollect any specific known issue here w.r.t Iphone version.

To help you further, can you clarify the following

1. Have you tried the sample as it is from the blog and did that work ?
   2.Can you share the wireshark trace from datapower gateway  , and if you see any difference in the flow between the devices ?

Comment: Observed the Datapower logs. The request from iPhone 7 Plus device going to api/preauth/v1/preauthorize but request from iPhone 6 is going to api/registration/v1/self. Why this difference?

Comment: Like vivin has updated, Registration gets called for the first time login from a device. otherwise for subsequent logins (on a successful registration), preAuth gets called. From your explanation, it looks like failing scenario registration is getting called, and if it is successful, you will see a preAuth post that. So we need to see registration response